# What is the elemental ratio of Monsters in a Dungeon of X?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Some of the first Normal Dungeons are "Dungeon of Fire", "Dungeon of Water", Wood, Light, and Darkness. In these Dungeons, do only enemies of that type appear, or do they simply appear at a higher rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the enemies in any given dungeon will be of the type of the dungeon. For instance, in the Dungeon of Fire (or any dungeon), you can sometimes encounter a [Dragon Seed](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Seed).

Here are the lists of monsters in each dungeon from the wiki:

1. [Dungeon of Fire](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_of_Fire) (Dragon Seed)
2. [Dungeon of Darkness](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_of_Darkness) (Blue Goblin, Goblin, Dragon Seed)
3. [Dungeon of Light](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_of_Light) (Red Goblin, Blue Goblin, Dragon Seed)
4. [Dungeon of Water](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_of_Water) (Dragon Seed)
5. [Dungeon of Wood](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_of_Wood) (No non-wood element monsters)